# If I wrote code for a personal project, and use some of it in a program at my company, can they now sue me for using the code in my personal project?

Tags: intellectual-property

Let's say I developed a web app for a personal endeavour of mine. Soon after, I get a job with a tech company, and my first task is to develop a web app for them. Well, it turns out the functionality of this new company web app is similar to my personal web app, and so I use some of the code from my personal web app in the company's web app. Can the company now sue me or take other legal action if I continue developing my personal web app? If so, how can I put a "license" in my code to protect my intellectual property (since I wrote the code BEFORE I even took the job)?

For the programmers out there, the code language is JavaScript and CSS.

Comment: They can sue you if you never worked for them or wrote any code at all. I think what you mean to ask is "Can they SUCCESSFULLY" sue you.

Comment: Did you sign an "inventions agreement"? It is a very common contract that you'll be required to sign as a condition of employment. It's purpose is to spell out and memorialize the conditions under which your employer becomes the owner of anything you invent in the course of your employment. As a programmer, this generally means any code you write. That document will have the answer. It should be noted that if it is overly broad it may not be enforceable. Typically, anything you do for the benefit of the company, on company time or using company resources will belong to the company.

Comment: Side note: When you employer gave you the task of developing a web app, they (implicitly) ordered you to *"write code from scratch that does X, because that will give us full ownership of the code"*. In particular, they did **not** order you to *"copy code that someone else (including your past self) has already written and which will give our legal department a lot of headaches"*.

Comment: You shouldn't be in a hurry to use code from your side projects at work.  If its previously published and widely acknowledged then its not that crazy, but otherwise not a good idea.  Managers can get paranoid and possessive often, why give them ammunition.

Comment: This is only perhaps tangential, but one possibility is if you have the authority to select and leverage open-source libraries - then you could release your personal code as open source under a license compatible with your company's needs and then be in the clear. If you don't want a public compatible license then it becomes a licensing issue between you and the company.

Comment: Is the code entered into a 3rd party repository such as GitHub, with timestamps *which pre-date* your start of employment?

Comment: @Heinzi As a developer, I really can't say that I agree, at least not completely. Unless you are writing the operating system from scratch (and probably in assembly,) you are almost always including someone else's code in every project ever developed and any reasonable employer of software developers knows this. Whether a particular piece of code is reasonable to use for a project or not then comes down to the specific license terms.

Comment: @reirab: Sure, a developer can (and should) *suggest* inclusion of a third-party library if it makes sense. Since every dependency is a long-term liability, the *decision* to do so should not be up to the individual (junior) developer, though. In my comment, "from scratch" means "using the pre-approved tech stack".

Comment: @Heinzi Most companies do **not** have a "preapproved tech stack".

Comment: @GACy20: Those who don't end up in "dependency hell" pretty quickly. Thus, in my experience, most *professional* software development companies do have a well-defined approval process for adding dependencies to their tech stack. YMMV, of course.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In the US, code that you write in the course of employment is the property of your employer. Otherwise, anything that you create is your property. The gray area is things that you write *during* your employment but not in the course of your employment (hence the terms of the employment contract are vital).

Something that you write before becoming an employee is not "in the course of employment". However, if you use that code in the in the course of employment, you invite the argument that in fact the code was written in the course of employment. That argument can be squelched if you have an agreement with the employer that acknowledges that you are *licensing* your code to the employer in exchange for ... some consideration. It could be $1, or a similar unit of currency.

Comment: It gets even murkier if you wrote that code using any company equipment or resources.

Comment: @JohnFx I have always seen that scenario as far less grey than people like to think. Especially because my job offers/agreements have all specified that the use of any equipment or resources (servers/software/third-party services like Azure) provided by work makes the work property of the company. The only stuff not covered would be non-trade secret knowledge gained through employment such as general experience or company paid conferences/classes.

Comment: @Logarr do you mean that they allow you to keep your (newly acquired) skills with you when you leave? How generous of them. Where can I apply

Comment: Even if you wrote it before: without hard evidence that that was the case, you're likely screwed if things go sour

Comment: That's why the employment contract should read something like: you have the right to reuse any code, algorithms, or related ideas you generate for the company, as long as the code is generic enough to apply to projects that are not in competition with company software. Ex: you can't use Excel code to build LibreOffice, but you can use that linked-list-searching algorithm you came up with in an ML project.

Comment: In practice, it would be rare for the code not to be improved or revised in some way each time it is used in a new project. It’s unlikely that any source code significant enough to be the subject of a copyright lawsuit would not have any bug fixes or other changes made to it while the programmer was working for their former employer and integrating it into their product.

Comment: "if you use that code in the in the course of employment, you invite the argument that in fact the code was written in the course of employment" I mean, they can argue whatever the want but that would be clearly false in this case, right? How could something written on your own time, with your own equipment, before you even worked for the company be argued to have been "written in the course of employment"?

Comment: @Ajedi32 It would be false, but they might not know that, especially if you don't explicitly mention your intentions to use your previously-created code and discuss a license agreement _before_ you use it. Otherwise, they might think you just reused work code for a personal project and invented the excuse of already having it after the fact when confronted.

Answer (score 22):

Is your personal code Published somewhere public? Github?
If not, publish it. Give it a permissible licence.
**Then** ask your employer/project manager/collegues if they would allow a niche *public* library you wrote yourself, because it seems to solve the problem.

Comment: It's not published anywhere public at the moment

Comment: @user3163495: That's problematic. You should ensure any code you wrote outside of your employment but might use as part of that employment has been published prior to its becoming relevant to your employment. Doing otherwise is inviting trouble.

Comment: alternatively post a hash of your code somewhere persistent and public. In short: document that you had that code for yourself first

Comment: I suspect you would have to do all this *before* using the code for a company project. Attempting this retrospectively is far less likely to achieve the desired outcome.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Yes, definitely publish first, use later. I've bolded the "then" to make it more obvious.

Answer (score 9):

If you wrote it before you started your employment, it is your intellectual property.

***However***, you should not just arbitrarily include intellectual property that the company doesn't own in a project you are building for the company, without their knowledge and agreement.

Often it's expected that you will make use of open source code in the course of building the company's project, but that is explicitly licensed to the company (via being published with an open invitation for anybody to accept the open source license it's published with), and if the company wants you to use open source material it is presumably happy to comply with those license terms. (You *also* should not include open source material without knowing the company is happy to be bound by the open source licenses for this project; generally it's clear if that's the case because there is already lots of open source code included in the project codebase, but it would never hurt to ask what the policy is explicitly)

Unpublished code you just happen to have access to should ***never*** be included in the company's projects. Without a license the company may be on the hook for copyright infringement, and even worse could find itself trapped unable to continue developing its own products because it is unable to make further derivative works of the code it does not own and has no license to use!

Code you just happen to have access to because **you wrote it** is only slightly different, in that you would be able to enter into a license agreement with the company to ensure the above situation does not happen. But the company will want to have an explicit written license agreement, so you *absolutely* should not include your own code without talking to your boss. And they are unlikely to accept any license less permissive than an open source license (so you won't be able to keep your code private to just yourself and the company; they will need extensive rights to modify and distribute it after you have left the company).

If you do include this code that is owned by you, rather than by the company, you may also be inviting personal trouble. If there is no evidence of the fact that you wrote it prior to your work for this company they may believe you are stealing their property if you later use it, and then engage legal proceedings against you. Strictly speaking this *should* come out in your favour, but if there's little documented evidence of exactly the circumstances in which the code was first created, then you can't rely on a court to rule that you should be the owner, even if that is the truth. So **you** should want an explicit written license agreement before using this code int he company project too, so that you later have proof that the company acknowledged your prior ownership.

But really, the *company* does not (or at least should not) want to get into that situation of disputed ownership in the first place. They would much rather you only included code that is either created during the course of your employment (so they own it completely) or is clearly licensed to the company (such as widely published open source code). Code you own but haven't published as open source prior to starting with the company, unless it is quite substantial, is probably just not worth the hassle for them of getting it properly licensed. Most likely paying developers to reinvent that wheel is cheaper than paying lawyers to make sure there are no legal issues.

Comment: I might change the first line to read "If you can prove you wrote it before you started your employment, it is your intellectual property."

Comment: @CGCampbell If you honestly created it first, then it ***IS*** your intellectual property. Lack of proof doesn't mean you don't *own* it, it just means that a court may not be able to enforce your property rights if the company falsely claims (in error or malice) they own it. Just as if you legally obtain physical property but have no evidence of your ownership, then if you loan it to someone (or leave it unsecured and they take it) a court may not be able to enforce your property rights if they falsely claim they own the physical property. I mention the practicality in my answer, anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately, here the OP has stated in a comment that the code was unpublished by them, and now they are coding under contract for a company. If the OP cannot _prove_ they wrote it before employment, the company is well within their rights to enforce ownership. The OP has used the code in a project for them. They own the code, unless the OP can _prove_ it was written before employment. This is what I meant. Not in general, but rather in _this specific case_.

Comment: @CGCampbell I don't believe that's the case, at least in my jurisdiction. Employers own code that was **actually** created during the course of your employment; they don't own "all code that you can't prove wasn't created during the course of your employment". And copyright ownership doesn't require publication. It's pragmatically similar of course, because if nobody can prove it either way there will be a dispute that a court will have to decide, and the company will have better lawyers. But the proof doesn't create ownership, it just helps a court rule your way if there is a dispute.

Comment: Ahh, ok, I see that. Thank you for the follow ups.

Answer (score 8):

You *can* be sued for anything. You will likely *get* sued if someone believes you caused them damage. With the facts as you describe them (you wrote software in your spare time at your own expenses, you "donated" it to your company) you never caused any damage, but if the company doesn't know the details, and all they know is that some code X is both in their product, and in your private product, they are likely to assume that you damaged them.

So I would strongly recommend that you talk to your manager at least before using any of your own code, and be prepared that the company doesn't allow it and that they don't want anything in their products where they are not the copyright owner. Making sure that you can't turn around in two years time and demand that your code gets removed could easily be more expensive than paying you or someone else to write code with the same functionality.

Comment: [Answering "Can I be sued" questions](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224/answering-can-i-be-sued-questions)

Comment: Barmar, I used SIX words for a clarification. SIX. So go and sue me for it.

Comment: Sorry, I just get tired of this frequent pedanticism, and you happened the be the victim when I decided to look up the site's concensus on it.

Answer (score 6):

At least once I was asked to provide a list of code I had already written (standard utility stuff that mostly now happens in libraries) *at hire*. Other times I supplied it myself, unasked.

A prenup is often a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

I think the key point here is to talk to your employer early, namely the moment you notice that code you already wrote for your personal project is useful for the task you got from the employer. There is potential for a win-win here because if the code the company needs already exists they can get it cheaper and faster than if you have to rewrite it from scratch. You just have to talk to them and find a mutually acceptable agreement. They get the code (and it is their intellectual property afterwards) and you get something from them, cash or some other work priviledges that you want. As both sides can win here this shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: "They get the code *(and it is their intellectual property afterwards)*" [emph. mine] would seem excessive - and problematic if it's already licensed to others.  Surely they shouldn't get more than a licence

Comment: @ChrisH True, just selling them the code would be one option, negotiating a licence or some other deal is also possible.

Answer (score 2):

The actual problem here is the liability that you are exposing the company to.  You are including code in their product that someone other than the company (you) has a prior copyright claim to.  You probably signed something saying you wouldn't do this when you joined the company.

I think that making your previously written code public somewhere with an MIT-style open source license (or something else that explicitly says commercial derivatives are fine and obligation-free) would probably eliminate the problem.

**It is still best to check**.  Just tell someone the situation and ask them if it's ok to use your code.